# How to put this logic into code/math?

Tags: java, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Okay so I am coding this program that has a user think of a number between 1 and 100 and then the computer (With 8 guesses max) will guess this number 100% of the time (assuming the user is giving correct info. The user simply says whether the computers past guess is too high or too low then the computer adjusts its next guess to what it knows. The logic is similar to this.

- First: "Is it greater than 50?" NO. So it's between 1 and 50.
- Second: "Is it greater than 25?" YES. So it's between 26 and 50.
- Third: "Is it greater than 38?" NO. So it's between 26 and 38.
- Fourth: "Is it greater than 32?" NO. So it's between 26 and 32.
- Fifth: "Is it greater than 29?" NO. So it's between 26 and 29.
- Sixth: "Is it greater than 27?" YES. So it's either 28 or 29.
- Seventh: "Is it 28?" NO. So it's 29.
- Eighth: "Is it 29?" YES.

So the way I am thinking of it is you have a variable x=50 if that's too high then you divide by 2 and x is changed to 25 if 25 is too low then you would multiply by 1.5

Okay so the question is how on earth do you put this into code. I just need the if statements not fully written out (loop) I don't want to write it 8 times (which I guess I could do) I can make the loop I just need the basics of the code/math.

Reply:
This isnt homework its a project im working on (teaching myself).
This is in Java.
Theres more to the code this is just a portion.

Comment: C#, Java, pseudo-code?...

Comment: Honestly this looks like homework.

Comment: we could do this for you - and you learn what?

Comment: The logic you have is wrong. Think about how you'd do it if you had to do the computer's job. Would you really just keep track of one number? Would that be enough to solve the problem?

Comment: If you'll notice, the logic is that the computer knows at each **step** that the guessed number is between `x` and `y`. So the computer **asks** about a number `z` **halfway between** `x` and `y`. Depending on whether the number guessed was **over or under** `z`, you'll **set** either `x` or `y` to `z`, and **try again** with a smaller range.

Comment: yes but how do you get between x and y

Comment: This is called a [**binary search**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Number_guessing_game).

Answer (score 1):

> So the way I am thinking of it is you have a variable x=50 if that's too high then you divide by 2 and x is changed to 25 if 25 is too low then you would multiply by 1.5

That will work okay for the initial iteration since, if 50 is too low, multiplying by 1.5 will get you 75. If it's too high, dividing by 2 will get you 25. In both cases, you move to the midpoint of the new range.

However, let's say your number is 99. Following that first question, your new midpoint will be 75 and you'll ask the question again. Since 75 is *still* too low, you multiply it by 1.5 and end up with around 112, which is well outside the possible range of values.

---

What you need to do is, rather than a simple multiplication of the midpoint value, work out the new midpoint based on the *size of the current range.* You _could maintain another variable with the delta value (which is added to, or subtracted from, the current midpoint to get the new midpoint) which starts at 25 and halves for each iteration.

Simply put, this is an application of a binary search (or chop). But there's a much easier way, using just high and low bounds (with a calculated midpoint) and adjust *one* of those bounds based on the answer from the user.

In pseudo-code, that would be something like (slightly modified to get responses of `yes`, `more` and `less`:

```
set low to 1                # starting range
set high to 100
set answer to 'more'        # force entry to loop
until answer is 'yes':
    if high is low:         # only one possibility left
        say 'Aaah, it must be ', high
        exit

    mid = (high + low) / 2  # choose midpoint and ask about it
    say 'Is it ', mid
    get answer

    if answer is 'yes':     # if match, claim victory and exit
        say "I got it."
        exit

    if answer is 'more':    # otherwise adjust range depending on answer
        low = mid + 1       # - must be greater than mid
    else:
        high = mid - 1      # - must be less that mid
```

This is a much simpler solution, one that also prevents a problem most beginners find when doing their first binary search, that of getting caught in an infinite loop at the end because (for example) `(28 + 29) / 2` gives you `28` again, meaning you may never examine element number `29`. In the above pseudo code, the fact that the new range is excluding the old midpoint means that this cannot happen.

---

As an addendum, here's the Python (2.7, Python 3 may need to use `input` instead of `raw_input`) code which implements the above (similar enough to show why I consider Python the ultimate pseudo-code language):

```
import sys

low = 1
high = 100
answer = "more"
while answer != "yes":
    if high == low:
        print 'Aaah, it must be', high
        sys.exit()

    mid = (high + low) / 2
    print 'Is it', mid
    answer = raw_input()

    if answer == "yes":
        print "I got it."
        sys.exit()

    if answer == "more":
        low = mid + 1
    else:
        high = mid - 1
```

I won't provide the same in Java since (1) I suspect this may be classwork and (2) you'll become a better developer if you do it yourself, classwork or not.

Answer (score 0):

Logic: Binary search. There is plenty of info on this topic in the Internet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm
If you read it you will understand why 8 guesses are enough for the range of 100.

Implementation in Java code: There is pseudo-code in the link above and ready-to-use java code in the Internet. If you want to learn, my advice is - implement it yourself.